# XCTKVOExpectation times out even though element exists

Tags: swift, android-espresso, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xctestexpectation

I am using swift, xcode 8.3.3, and XCTest.  I am trying to wait for an element to exist on the screen using XCTKVOExpectation.  It is always returning the result of timedout (2) even though the element exists.

Here is my code:

```
func waitForElementToAppear(element: XCUIElement) -> Bool {
    let expectation = XCTKVOExpectation(keyPath: "exists", object: element,
                                        expectedValue: true)

    let result = XCTWaiter().wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10)
    print(element.exists)
    print(result.rawValue)
    return result == .completed
}
```

When I print element.exists, it prints true.  However the result.rawValue is 2 (.timedout)  Increasing the timeout value did not resolve this either.

I am able to successfully use XCTNSPredicateExpectation:

```
    let myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    let myExpectation = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: myPredicate,
                                                object: element)

    let result = XCTWaiter().wait(for: [myExpectation], timeout: 10)
    return result == .completed
```

Wondering why XCTKVOExpectation doesn't work though?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but I've been seeing this in Xcode 9.3.1 as well. The exact same predicate combination works well elsewhere in many places but one in particular *almost* always times out.

I've worked around it for now by checking whether the object exists before issuing the wait, and then also "result == XCTWaiterResultCompleted || object.exists" (Objective C).

I'd love to know if this is a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with my own code. I was able to get the KVO change to trigger using `didChangeValue(forKey: "keyValuePath")`.

Since XCTKVOExpectation accepts a String for the key path instead of a KeyPath, paired with needing to call `didChangeValue(forKey: "keyValuePath")`, it seems XCTKVOExpectation is not meant to work with Swift and is more of a legacy objc object. I just don't think this is going to work in Swift